# What does "thereby effectively allowed to stand" mean in this extract?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Please explain the meaning of the phrase "thereby effectively allowed to stand" as said in the below paragraph.

> “If these election irregularities are not fully investigated prior to
> Inauguration Day and thereby effectively allowed to stand, this nation
> runs the very real risk of never being able to have a fair
> presidential election again,” Navarro said in his report.

Comment: Which word don't you understand, and what did the dictionary say that confused you? Did you mean to post this to [ell.se] instead?

Comment: I gather that "allowed to stand" confuses you.  It's an idiom, meaning that the "irregularities" (or whatever item of contention is being discussed) are not somehow resolved/answered by the stated deadline.

Comment: [{they are} thereby] [effectively] [allowed to stand] = [by failing to investigate them before inauguration day] [the bottom line is that, {by failing to take action}] [{we are} allowing these irregularities to pass unchallenged, and encouraging future such irregularities]

Answer (score 2):

This is a reasonable question that cannot be answered merely by dictionary work. I do not repeat all the definitions here but if we look for example in the Cambridge Dictionary online we get

Thereby = as a result of this (failure to investigate)

Effectively = in a way that is successful and achieves what you want

Or effectively = used when you describe what the real result of a situation is:

Allowed = Permitted or similar meaning. Other meanings are also given.

To stand = there are too many meanings of stand for me to list. One that is relevant here is :

> Stand = to be in a particular state or situation
>
> ([Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stand?q=Stand)

To understand such English from dictionary work therefore requires the reader to choose from too many possible combinations of these definitions to reach a reliable conclusion. Even some less literate native speakers would have difficulty in comprehending the combination of the four elements.

It means:

If the irregularities are not investigated and are permitted to be uncorrected until Inauguration Day, they will remain as precedents and examples that corrupt future election processes.

Comment: 'To understand such English from dictionary work therefore requires the reader to choose from too many possible combinations of these definitions to reach a reliable conclusion. Even some less literate native speakers would have difficulty in comprehending the combination of the four elements',  I'd argue, takes us into comprehension, understanding extended extracts, which is off-topic as not focused enough for ELU.

Comment: Perhaps, but how else are we to help a reasonable questioner?

Comment: There are all sorts of questions involving English language / literature that are 'reasonable', but off-topic on ELU. Some are basic; many of these are properly asked on ELL. Many lack evidence of reasonable research. Some are questions about style choices. Some ask for translations, guesswork, proofreading. Some aren't sufficiently narrowly scoped.  They're all _reasonable_ to ask elsewhere. Answering off-topic questions encourages more such questions.

Comment: A point that you have made previously and one I agree with, although to a lesser extent. We cannot shape the world according to our own notions.

Comment: If I didn't think the regs on ELU were worth upholding, I wouldn't try so hard to see them observed. There are many 'English' websites I don't visit. But if I had a problem with a passage say, after doing my best using the usual reference works,  I'd try to find a good site where comprehension **is** on-topic.

Comment: 1. "Even some less literate native speakers would have difficulty" The interpretation is not just a matter of literacy but of underspecified grammar. It might be undecidable, in effect. The problem is that inaction doesn't require any agent; allowing would but an active subject isn't immediate. Your solution shifts the independent clause's subject, "irregularities will remain" practicly to passive, making it unavailable for the dependent clause. Whereas "the nation runs [at risk]" means the recipient and is at least ambiguous.

Comment: 2. The semantics problem is, who was supposed to have "investigated"? The formal syntax problem is, how is the AdvP. to be parsed? "thereby effectively" has two meaning, as you showed. Both interpretations are applicable, but require different interpretation of the syntax and agents (oops: I haven't studied formal syntax). Your solution is optimal, insofar it removes the illusion of a known subject (the nation), as we require a sentence to have the same truth value for all recipients. Although, closer to the truth would be opposite interpretations split along party lines.

Comment: PS: I meant to say, *allowing would [require an agent] but an active subject isn't immediate[ly available]*. PPS: I meant to express the opinion that the example is a case of double speak or news speak. "effectively" appears like a weasel-word, if you can remove it effectively without effectively changing the syntax, effectively. But it does make a difference depending only on how you *want* to interpret it. That makes it a political problem, if you *want* to take action against *someone*, and/or want *someone else* to act or much rather *not to* act.